# Scala intermediate early initializer

Tags: scala, traits, scalatest, fixtures

Is there a way in scala to use an intermediate early initializer?

Here is what I'm trying to compile:

```scala
trait A { val valueA: Int = 0 }
trait B { 
  val valueB: Int 
  println(valueB)
}


class C extends A with { val valueB = valueA } with B
```

EDIT: reponse to Luis' question

With scalatest, fixtures can be organized with trait constructors. I'd like to parameterize one subfixture and early initialize with a field from a superfixture.

Here is another example that relates better to a real scalatest case:

```scala
class Test extends FreeSpec {
  trait CommonFixture {
    val commonCaseValue: Int = 1
  }
  abstract trait SpecialCaseFixture {
    val specialCaseValue: Int
  }

  "special case test #1" in new CommonCaseFixture with { val specialCaseValue = commonCaseValue } with SpecialCaseFixture {
    // all fixtures fields are accessible here
  }
}
```

Comment: As per scala syntax `EarlyDefs` must be before any other parent class or trait. - https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates

Comment: Can you tell us why you want this? Maybe there are better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override it with a `lazy val`:

```
trait A { val valueA: Int = 100500 }
trait B {
  val valueB: Int
  println(valueB)
}
class C extends A with B { lazy val valueB = valueA } 
new C 
// prints 100500
```

Comment: It prints 0 because it is the uninitialized value of `Int`, try with another integer.

Comment: @montrivo YOU "try with another integer" :)

Comment: My bad, I had removed the lazy modifier while trying your example. So lazy it is.. :) Thanks!

Comment: Here is a scala forum thread on the topic: 
https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6077

Answer (score 1):

There are likely alternative ways to write the tests without having to use early initialisers (which are deprecated), for example the following might give some ideas

```
class FixturesSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  case class FixtureA(x: Int = 42)
  case class FixtureB(y: Int = -11)

  trait CommonFixture {
    val commonCaseValue: Int = 1
  }
  trait SpecialCaseFixture {
    val specialCaseValue: Int
  }

  "traits" should "be fixtures" in new SpecialCaseFixture with CommonFixture  {
    override val specialCaseValue = commonCaseValue
    specialCaseValue should be (1)
  }

  "case classes" should "be fixtures" in new FixtureA(FixtureB().y)  {
    x should be (-11)
  }
}
```

Comment: The example doesn't solve `SpecialCaseFixture.specialCaseValue` not being available during initialization. If you add a `println` statement in `SpecialCaseFixture`'s body, it will print `null`.